# How to disable a TypeScript error for the whole project?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Following a TypeScript bug that has no fix yet (that triggers a false positive), I would like to disable a TypeScript error for my whole project. How can we do that?

I want to disable:

- only one type of error
- not for one line or one file but for the entire project

I found a GitHub issue but it has not been implemented yet: [tsconfig - Ignore errors by ids #29950](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29950).

P.-S. Here's the TypeScript bug I mentioned above: [Using Box from MUI cause error #823](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/issues/823)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use [tcs-silent](https://dev.to/15five/how-to-temporarily-ignore-errors-during-a-typescript-migration-doe). This seems to allow you to ignore specific errors throughout your project.

Comment: I think I can. I am a bit unhappy with using this specific wrapper just to suppress one error but it looks like I don't have other options.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but I struggle to configure it with create-react-app https://github.com/evolution-gaming/tsc-silent/issues/17